# Correlated Sub Queries in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

Can you please let me know how to convert the below sql server code to Snowflake, since Snowflake doesn't
support correlated sub queries.

`SELECT DISTINCT`
`CURRENT_DATE as creationdate, LastName,`
`(SELECT Date AS Exp1`
 `FROM    PSU AS P`
`WHERE   (HQL = a.B1L) AND (HQH = a.B1H) AND`
`(HQN =`
`(SELECT     MAX(HQN) AS Exp1`
`FROM          PSU AS P2`
`WHERE      (HQL = a.B1L) AND (HQH = a.B1H) AND (HQZ = 'P') AND (HQF = 'P'))))AS "paymentDATE",`
`(CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(H6P)`
`FROM     sss`
`WHERE  H6P = B1L AND H6CPS NOT IN ('H', 'C')) IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END)` `AS "ORDER(Y/N)"`
`FROM    ACT AS a INNER JOIN`
`CU AS c ON c.BSL = a.B1L INNER JOIN`
`CS AS cs ON cs.B2L = a.B1L AND a.B1H = cs.B2H`
`WHERE     (a.B1M <> 0) AND (cs.B2K IN ('H'))`

Snowflake code I created for the above code, I didn't create a CTE yet for "ORDER(Y/N)" field: I feel the joins are not correct in CTE and not sure how to join the CTE to main query

`WITH RECURSIVE  PaymentDate AS`
`(SELECT MAX(HQN) AS Expr1`
`FROM  PSU AS P2` 
`JOIN  POP AS a ON (P2.HQL = a.B1L) AND (P2.HQH= a.B1H) AND (P2.HQZ = 'P') AND` `(P2.HQF= 'P')`
`)`
`, LPD AS`
`(SELECT  Date as Exp1   FROM`
`PSU AS P`
`JOIN  ACT AS A ON (P.HQL = a.B1L) AND (P.HQH = a.B1H)`
`JOIN  TNR ON (P.HQN =TNR.Expr1)`
`)`
`SELECT DISTINCT  CURRENT_DATE as creationdate, LastName`
`(CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(H6P) FROM     sss WHERE  H6P = B1L AND H6CPS NOT IN` `('H', 'C'))` 
`IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END) AS "ORDER(Y/N)"` 
`FROM     ACT AS a INNER JOIN`
`CU AS c ON c.BSL = a.B1L` 
`INNER JOIN CS AS cs ON cs.B2L = a.B1L AND a.B1H = cs.B2H` 
`WHERE  (a.B1M <> 0) AND (cs.B2K IN ('H'))`

Answer (score 0):

If you re-write both sub-queries as CTEs that should work.

First CTE gets these values:
HQL, HQH, MAX(HQN)

Second CTE joins PSU to the first CTE to get the "paymentDATE"

Join the 2nd CTE into your main query

Comment: Thanks Nick, for your comment. I created CTE's but I am missing some where in the joins... can you please create the SF code and show it.

Comment: In order to be able to write the actual code I would need to be able to test it. If you want me to do that please provide the table creation scripts, sample data and the expected result dataset. Alternatively, if you provide your CTE SQL I could check it for possible issues

Comment: Nick, I added the SF code that I created in the question. I tried to paste the code in comment section, but it says characters exceeded, so I added in question. Can you please correct the code and send me the SF code.